# Network analysis compare travel time between a fire truck and a helicopter

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst

I am working with ArcGIS Pro and supposed to create a map that shows the different travel time between a fire truck and a helicopter. I'm supposed to show where the fire truck is faster than the ambulance helicopter. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. The purpose of your assignment is for *you* to learn how to do this task. The answer to your question is certainly "Yes," but that's not going to help you. If you demonstrate an attempt to solve the task, we can help untangle you, but you need to put some effort into the problem first.

Answer (score 2):

Some questions you should ask yourself are these:

- Do you have a velocity model for the helicopter or is the speed of the helicopter supposed to be constant - and what speed is that?
- Are there takeoff and landing delays?
- Do you have to take terrain into account? Can the heli climb at any rate/does it need to go around mountains?
- Are there flight restriction zones, e.g. around the airport?
- (How) is the routing of a firetruck different from routing a normal car?

For the sake of simplicity, lets assume the heli has a constant speed of 200km/h, no takeoff delay, and the firetruck is driven like a normal car.

Then the distance the heli is able to cover in (say) 5 minutes is just its airspeed divided by 60 and multiplied by 5.

```
dist_heli_km = (200/60)*5 = 16,66
```

So you create a buffer around the helipad with a distance of 16,66 km.

Then you create the isochrones (lines of equal travel time) using the ArcGIS Pro Network analysis tool, see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/analysis/networks/network-analyst-solver-types.htm . You probably need the "service area" solver.

Then select the service area layer features where the helicopter buffer intersects the service area layer and the service area edge times are under 5 minutes.